# Can not import package installed in anaconda in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

`pywin32` Package is installed in anaconda, when a package is imported it gives an error in pycharm. I am using the anaconda interpreter in pycharm. It gives the same error in spyder.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:/Users/zahid/PycharmProjects/untitled3/test.py", line 1, in  <module>  
from pywinauto.application import Application  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywinauto'
```

[image: Anaconda Terminal]
[image: PyCharm image]
Kindly help to resolve issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have not installed the [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) module.

Use

```
pip install pywinauto
```

to install it.